# Find the path of an object in which there is a key with a speicific in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js

Let's say I have the array of dictionaries like below. How do I find a path to the object with `id: 121`. I am trying to do this in javascript, but I am not getting anywhere with this. I need an algorithm or something to get an idea for acheiving this.

The result I am expecting is something like `[{id:1, name:"foo"}, {id: 12, name:"shoo"}, {id: 121, name:"jhj"}]`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "submenus": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "bar",
                "submenus": [
                    {
                        "id": 111,
                        "name": "abc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "shoo",
                "submenus": [
                    {
                        "id": 121,
                        "name": "jhj"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "kjk"
    }
]
```

this is the code I wrote for it. This code is for VueJS.

```
getBreadcrumbs(menuItems, id, breadcrumpsArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
      if (menuItems[i].id == id) {
        breadcrumpsArray.push({
          id: menuItems[i].id,
          name: menuItems[i].text
        })
        return breadcrumpsArray
      } else {
        if (menuItems[i].submenus !== 'undefined') {
          if (menuItems[i].submenus.length > 0) {
            console.log('shoo')
            this.getBreadcrumbs(menuItems[i].submenus, id, breadcrumpsArray)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This shows error saying:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: menuItems[i].submenus is undefined"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a recursive function `findPath()` to achieve what you require. See the notes documented in the snippet below:

```js
const data=[{"id":1,"name":"foo","submenus":[{"id":11,"name":"bar","submenus":[{"id":111,"name":"abc"}]},{"id":12,"name":"shoo","submenus":[{"id":121,"name":"jhj"}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"kjk"}];

/* Define a recursive function that finds the item path from root
of the data set, to the first child found with matching id */
const findPath = (items, id) => {
    
    /* Iterate the items of this level */
    for(const item of items) {

        if(item.id === id) {
            /* If id matches id, return tail of resulting array that 
            will be our path result */
            return [item]
        }
        else if(Array.isArray(item.submenus)) {
            /* If submenus sub array present, search the items of the
            submenu recursivly for a nested child with matching id */
            const result = findPath(item.submenus, id)
            if(Array.isArray(result)) {
                /* If recursive call returns an array result, this means
                a nested child with id was found, so prefix this item to
                the results array */
                return [item].concat(result)
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Map id and name of each item in found path to result array */
const result = findPath(data, 121).map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }));

console.log( result );
```

Also as a separate note, in your current code this is a minor error in the way you're checking for the presence of the `submenus` sub-array on menu items.

Applying the following change should result the error you are seeing:

```
getBreadcrumbs(menuItems, id, breadcrumpsArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].id == id) {

            breadcrumpsArray.push({
                id: menuItems[i].id,
                name: menuItems[i].text
            });

        } else {

            /* Add "typeof" here to determine if submenus if undefined in this way */
            if (typeof menuItems[i].submenus !== 'undefined') {
                if (menuItems[i].submenus.length > 0) {
                    this.getBreadcrumbs(menuItems[i].submenus, id, breadcrumpsArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Move this here */
    return breadcrumpsArray;
}
```

For more information on this `typeof` operator, [see this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: Sorry but this means you will only push to `breadcrumpsArray` if you found the node, what he wants is the path. I don't mean to be annoying it's cause I am trying to figure it out for him and I am failing haha

Comment: @AliElKhateeb just updated answer above - does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You could find the path and if found take an object for the node into the result set.

```js
function findPath(array, target) {
    var path;
    return array.some(({ id, name, submenus = [] }) => {
            if (id === target) return path = [{ id, name }];
            var temp = findPath(submenus, target);
            if (temp.length) return path = [{ id, name }, ...temp];
        })
        ? path
        : [];
}

var array = [{ id: 1, name: "foo", submenus: [{ id: 11, name: "bar", submenus: [{ id: 111, name: "abc" }] }, { id: 12, name: "shoo", submenus: [{ id: 121, name: "jhj" }] }] }, { id: 2, name: "kjk" }];;

console.log(findPath(array, 121))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to do that, here is my algorithm's steps:

- First, [DFS (Depth First Search)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) your tree until you find the node with the `id` you're looking for
- When you find it, push it to `breadscrumpArray` and return `breadscrumpArray`
- Everytime we search a `submenu` element we will know if the node we are looking for is a child of that element or not, as if it is not a child, the return of the function `getBreadcrumbs` will be `false`

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions in the comments, cheers!

```js
function getBreadcrumbs(menuItems, id, breadcrumpsArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].id == id) {
            // Found the node, push it and return the breadcrumpsArray
            breadcrumpsArray.push({
                id: menuItems[i].id,
                name: menuItems[i].name
            });
            return breadcrumpsArray;
        } else {
            if (typeof menuItems[i].submenus !== 'undefined') {
                if (menuItems[i].submenus.length > 0) {
                    if (getBreadcrumbs(menuItems[i].submenus, id, breadcrumpsArray)) {
                        // Unshift to push the node to the front of the array
                        breadcrumpsArray.unshift({
                            id: menuItems[i].id,
                            name: menuItems[i].name
                        });
                        return breadcrumpsArray;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // The node we are looking for is not in this path of the tree
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns false :(

Comment: That's true, something must have gone wrong when I tried it. Upvoted.